# ReactJs useState Array Map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I have doubts on how I can do this in react using useState,
basically i have this menu where i need to map, i basically need a state containing all tags, and with boolean state true or false to know if the current item is active, and i will make it active by clicking on the item, and deactivate it when another item is clicked

that is, only one menu item active at a time

```
export const SideBarTags = [
  {
    name: 'Tutoriais',
    link: '../tutorials',
    icon: faFileAlt,
    dropdownItems: null,
    active: false,
  },
  {
    name: 'Avisos',
    link: '../news',
    icon: faNewspaper,
    dropdownItems: null,
    active: false,
  },
  {
    name: 'Serviços',
    link: '../services',
    icon: faMeteor,
    active: false,
    dropdownItems: [
      { name: 'Elo Boost', link: '/eloBost' },
      { name: 'Duo Boost', link: '/duoBoost' },
      { name: 'MD10', link: '/eloBost' },
      { name: 'Coaching', link: '/duoBoost' },
      { name: 'Vitóriais', link: '/duoBoost' },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'Carteira',
    link: '../cartcredit',
    icon: faWallet,
    active: false,
    dropdownItems: [
      { name: 'Histórico', link: '/history' },
      { name: 'Adicionar Crédito', link: '/add' },
    ],
  },
];
```

and my TSX:

```
const MenuTags: React.FC<Hamburguer> = ({ isOpen }) => {
    const [menuTags, setMenuTags] = useState(SideBarTags.map());

  return (
    <DashMenu open={isOpen}>
    <MenuItem /> //(this is my tag <li>
    </DashMenu>
  );
};



const MenuItem: React.FC = () => {


  return (
    <ListItem>
      <ListWrap

      >
        <a>
          <FontAwesomeIcon
            className="icon-li"
            icon={icon}
            size={isOpen ? 'lg' : 'lg'}
            fixedWidth
            color="white"
          />
          <span
            className="li-name"
          >
            {name}
          </span>
        </a>
    </ListItem>
  );
};
```

Comment: You might be better using `useReducer` for more complex state - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

Comment: Where is your react code showing what you tried so far?

Comment: @Jon B I'm having a problem with how to map my array into my useState or useReducer and what is the difference between the two ?:

like this:

useState (menuTags.map (logic here));

Comment: @MonteCristo i go edit question now, i forgot, sorry for my mistake

Comment: Why not just store, separately, in component state an active item? Give all your menu items an unique id property and use that to determine what is active.

Comment: @Drew Reese Do you talk about mapping each item with state?

I do this, but I got a problem because I use two types of menus, mapping the same tags, in which case I would have to have two different states, I don't know if that's what I understood, could you give me an example?

Comment: i edit the question with my code

Comment: No, just in whatever component is rendering the menu items you have a piece of state that simply maintains what menu item is active. If this was a flat array you could use the index, for example. Having nested items that aren't all using the same nesting means you have to switch to more of "global" identifier, just something unique in the entire set of menu items. If you provide an example of your menu rendering then I can perhaps amend with my suggestion how to maintain an active item.

Comment: @DrewReese i edit the question with my tsx code basically I have a <ul> tag
and my <li> tags
that I would render according to my array

Comment: I agree with @DrewReese this is how I have done it in the past, I didn't fully understand what you were asking before

Comment: @Jon B basically i will render 2 different sidebars (it open and it closed)

and then I need to map my array, and I'm only going to have only one active item, meaning the user clicks on a dropdown item the other one would close

Comment: Though now I see you do have a fairly flat structure of the main items that you want to toggle active/inactive. A simple mapping could achieve this but IMO it is easier to just maintain what is active separately and skipping the array mappings altogether.

Comment: BTW, it isn't clear what type of routing your app uses, but if you are using react-router-dom then there is a (NavLink](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink) that can handle much of this "logic" for you.

Comment: @Drew Reese yes i go use react-router-dom  but I'm using active more for my dropdown items, ie I will only have one <ul> dropdown open at a time

Comment: @DrewReese do you think there is a simpler solution with what I told you about the dropdown?

Comment: Ah no, I think both @JonB and I have said what the simpler solution would be, just tracking what menu item is active. His answer does that and mine shows how to do what I think you were asking. As you can see, the code is similar, but there's just a few more moving parts with maintaining what is active when you store it in the menu item array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Component logic if you wanted to map the menu items with the active item

```
const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState(SideBarTags);

const clickHandler = name => () => {
  setMenuItems(items =>
    items.map(item => ({
      ...item,
      active: item.name === name
    }))
  );
};

...

{menuItems.map(item => (
  <li
    key={item.name}
    className={item.active ? "active" : ""}
    onClick={clickHandler(item.name)}
  >
    {item.name}
  </li>
))}
```

CSS

```
.active {
  // could be whatever style you need
  color: red;
}
```

[image: Edit blissful-elbakyan-fpzn9]

Comment: can u help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61514434/react-with-ts-is-missing-the-following-properties-from-type

Comment: @gabriel Did you figure it out? I was in the middle of writing this comment when your post was deleted. I am not familiar with typescript but it is just saying the prop definitions don't align. To me it seemed you might've been using the wrong component in the menu mapping.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61515204/typesrcript-reactjs-is-missing-the-following-properties-from-type sorry i delete question for some reason my dropdown items have an empty array, i'm a little lost on how to solve this

Answer (score 3):

Super simplified version of what I did in a past project:

```
const MenuTags = () => {
  const [selectedLink, setSelectedLink] = useState(null)

  return (
    <ul>
      {SideBarTags.map((obj) => (
        <li className={`${selectedLink === obj.name ? 'link--selected' : ''}`}>
          <a
            onClick={() => {
              setSelectedLink(obj.name)
            }}
            href={obj.link}
          >
            {obj.name}
          </a>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Use CSS to open and close the menu items, by having a class such as 'link--selected' added to an element you can just show that item.