# typesrcript reactjs : is missing the following properties from type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following array with the following structure:

```
export const SideBarTags = [
  {
    name: 'Tutoriais',
    link: '../tutorials',
    icon: faFileAlt,
    dropdownItems: null,
    active: false,
  },
  {
    name: 'Avisos',
    link: '../news',
    icon: faNewspaper,
    dropdownItems: null,
    active: false,
  },
  {
    name: 'Serviços',
    link: '../services',
    icon: faMeteor,
    active: false,
    dropdownItems: [
      { name: 'Elo Boost', link: '/eloBost' },
      { name: 'Duo Boost', link: '/duoBoost' },
      { name: 'MD10', link: '/eloBost' },
      { name: 'Coaching', link: '/duoBoost' },
      { name: 'Vitóriais', link: '/duoBoost' },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'Carteira',
    link: '../cartcredit',
    icon: faWallet,
    active: false,
    dropdownItems: [
      { name: 'Histórico', link: '/history' },
      { name: 'Adicionar Crédito', link: '/add' },
    ],
  },
];
```

And so I'm trying to use it in a component react:

```
interface MenuItem {
  index: Number;
  tag: {
    name: String;
    link: String;
    icon: any;
    dropdownItems: any;
  };
  setVisible: Function;
  visibleMenu: boolean;
  isOpen: boolean;
}
const MenuItem: React.FC<MenuItem> = ({
  tag,
  visibleMenu,
  setVisible,
  index,
  isOpen,
}) => {
  const { name, dropdownItems, icon } = tag;
  const handleClick = (index) => {
    if (visibleMenu === true) return setVisible('none');
    if (visibleMenu === index) return setVisible('none');
    return setVisible(index);
  };

  return (

  );
};
const MenuTags: React.FC<MenuTags> = ({ sideisOpen }) => {
  const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState(SideBarTags);
  console.log(menuItems);

  return (
    <MenuList open={sideisOpen}>
      {menuItems.map((item, index) => (
        <MenuTagsItems
          key={item.name}
          menuItem={item}
          sideisOpened={sideisOpen}
          tagFunction={setMenuItems}
        />
      ))}
    </MenuList>
  );
};
```

but i got this error:

> Type '{ name: string; link: string; icon: IconDefinition; active:
>   boolean; dropdownItems: { name: string; link: string; }[]; }' is not
>   assignable to type '{ name: string; link: string; icon: any;
>   dropdownItems: { name: string; link: string; } | null; active:
>   boolean; }'.
>       Types of property 'dropdownItems' are incompatible.
>         Type '{ name: string; link: string; }[]' is missing the following properties from type '{ name: string; link: string; }':
>   name, link  TS2322

Comment: Could you please include your interfaces for SidebarTag and DropdownItem? Seems most likely your problem lies there.

Comment: I don't have interfaces for my SidebarTag

it's just a const i tried to apply interface but to no avail
and
my dropdownitens is part of my sidebartags is an array of objects I put in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your interface you've declared `dropdownItems` as any. Looking at you data it seems `dropdownItems` is an array of objects containing keys name and link.

You can split your interface like this. When using Typescript you should avoid using the any tag since it makes no sense to use any Typescript

```
import { IconName } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types';

export interface IDropdownItems {
  name: string;
  link: string;
}
export interface ITag {
  name: string;
  link: string;
  icon: IconName;
  dropdownItems: IDropdownItems[] | null;
  active: boolean;
}
export interface IMenuItem {
  index: number;
  tag: ITag;
  setVisible: (v: boolean) => void;
  visibleMenu: boolean;
  isOpen: boolean;
}

export const SideBarTags: ITag[] = [
  {
    name: "Tutoriais",
    link: "../tutorials",
    icon: "faFileAlt",
    dropdownItems: null,
    active: false
  },
  {
    name: "Avisos",
    link: "../news",
    icon: "faNewspaper",
    dropdownItems: null,
    active: false
  },
  {
    name: "Serviços",
    link: "../services",
    icon: "faMeteor",
    active: false,
    dropdownItems: [
      { name: "Elo Boost", link: "/eloBost" },
      { name: "Duo Boost", link: "/duoBoost" },
      { name: "MD10", link: "/eloBost" },
      { name: "Coaching", link: "/duoBoost" },
      { name: "Vitóriais", link: "/duoBoost" }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Carteira",
    link: "../cartcredit",
    icon: "faWallet",
    active: false,
    dropdownItems: [
      { name: "Histórico", link: "/history" },
      { name: "Adicionar Crédito", link: "/add" }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: u can help me ? i have problem on icon type, i use fortawesome and is this type: IconDefinition

Comment: const coffeeLookup: IconLookup = { prefix: 'fas', iconName: 'coffee' }
const coffeeIconDefinition: IconDefinition = findIconDefinition(coffeeLookup) I found this solution on github, but I'm not wondering how to apply it to my type

Comment: @gabriel I updated the interface with a type for Icon. Haven't tried it but should work